# Ordenar lista de classe em Python

Tags: python, lista, classes, classificação

Tenho uma classe definida da seguinte forma:

```
class Cromossomo():
    def __init__(self, cromossomo, comprimento):    #Construtor
        self.cromossomo = cromossomo 
        self.comprimento = comprimento
```

A partir dela eu tenho uma lista da classe Cromossomo. chamada lista final.

Quero ordenar essa lista de acordo com o comprimento, do maior para o menor.
Já tentei usar sort, sorted, mas não consegui.

Por exemplo:

```
def ordenar(lista_final):
    sorted(lista_final, key=attrgetter('comprimento'), reverse=True)


ordenar(lista_final)
```

Como faço para dar certo?

Comment: Essa lista final é composta de que?

Comment: atributo cromossomo e comprimento
ex:
lista_final[0].cromossomo = [1,0,0,1]
lists_final[0].comprimento = 25

Quero ordenar pelo comprimento

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você fez quase tudo certo, só na hora de definir a chave para ordenação que você se confundiu:

```
#Classe definida pelo AP
class Cromossomo():
    def __init__(self, cromossomo, comprimento):    #Construtor
        self.cromossomo = cromossomo 
        self.comprimento = comprimento
    
#Cria uma lista de teste
genoma = [Cromossomo(1,20), Cromossomo(2,10), Cromossomo(3,33), Cromossomo(4,2), Cromossomo(5,21), Cromossomo(6,30)]

#Ordena a lista baseada no comprimento do maior para o menor
genoma_ordenado = sorted(genoma, key=lambda x: x.comprimento,reverse=True)

#Imprime apenas os comprimentos da lista já ordenada
print([cromossomo.comprimento for cromossomo in genoma_ordenado])
```

Código funcionando no Repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/FamiliarCrimsonMp3

## Adendo:

Como mencionado nos comentários o AP não cometeu erros de codificação ele se confundiu e esqueceu de fazer uma importação, implicando em outra saída para correção do código que seria importar a função [`attrgette()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) do módulo [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html).

```
from operator import attrgetter
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Só para deixar registrado que não havia nada de errado como código do AP, provavelmente ele esqueceu de importar a função `attrgetter`. [Modifiquei o seu exemplo para demostrar](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-434818-6333). Deixo aqui como complemento.

Comment: Sem dúvidas, tanto que não disse que ele errou e sim "se confundiu"

Answer (score 0):

Poderia apenas adicionar um `return` na função `ordenar`...

```py
    from operator import attrgetter

    class Cromossomo():
        def __init__(self, cromossomo, comprimento):    #Construtor
            self.cromossomo = cromossomo 
            self.comprimento = comprimento
        
        def __repr__(self):
            return "\ncromossomo: " + str(self.cromossomo) + \
                   " comprimento: " + str(self.comprimento)

    def ordenar(lista_final, atributo, reverse=True):
        return sorted(lista_final, key=attrgetter(atributo), reverse=reverse)

    cromossomo1 = Cromossomo(1, 5)
    cromossomo2 = Cromossomo(2, 3)
    cromossomo3 = Cromossomo(3, 10)
    cromossomo4 = Cromossomo(4, 4)
    cromossomo5 = Cromossomo(5, 2)
    cromossomos = [cromossomo1, cromossomo2, cromossomo3, cromossomo4, cromossomo5]

    listaOrdenada = ordenar(cromossomos, 'comprimento')
    print(listaOrdenada)
```

Output:

```
[cromossomo: 3 comprimento: 10,
cromossomo: 1 comprimento: 5, 
cromossomo: 4 comprimento: 4, 
cromossomo: 2 comprimento: 3, 
cromossomo: 5 comprimento: 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia adicionar métodos especiais na sua classe, para o sorted funcionar normalmente no seu modo normal. Deixando a classe com o seguinte formato:

```
class Cromossomo():
    def __init__(self, cromossomo, comprimento):    #Construtor
        self.cromossomo = cromossomo 
        self.comprimento = comprimento


    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.comprimento < other.comprimento


    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.comprimento <= other.comprimento


    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.comprimento == other.comprimento


    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.comprimento >= other.comprimento


    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.comprimento > other.comprimento
```

Basicamente, o método especial **lt**, que seria less than, em português menor que, checa se o comprimento do objeto é menor que o comprimento do outro. Para os outros métodos, a lógica é parecida.

1. **le**: Menor ou igual
2. **eq**: Igual
3. **ge**: Maior ou igual
4. **gt**: Maior que

Basicamente, isso possibilita fazermos comparações diretas entre os objetos, se fizermos algo como:

```
Cromossomo(1,5) < Cromossomo(2,10)
```

O método **lt** estaria sendo utilizado, com o parâmetro 'self' sendo o objeto a esquerda da comparação e o parâmetro 'other' o que está no lado direito. O retorno para isso seria:

```
True
```

No final, para ordenar os cromossomos, bastaria colocá-los numa lista e realizar um:

```
lista.sort()
```

Informações e mais exemplos sobre esses métodos podem ser vistos no seguinte site: [https://twiserandom.com/python/**eq**-**ne**-**lt**-**gt**-**ge**-**le**-in-python-a-tutorial/index.html](https://twiserandom.com/python/__eq__-__ne__-__lt__-__gt__-__ge__-__le__-in-python-a-tutorial/index.html)